# How to display an image bigger than the listView (or gridView) cell?

Tags: java, android, listview, gridview, android-gridview

I have a listView and I want to display in a cell an image that is bigger than the cell height. But I don't want to crop this image that will overlap over one or several lines above and below this cell.

How can I do that ?

Thanks !

[image]

Comment: If you don't want to crop then you can fit center with specific size of your image view.

Answer (score 0):

Use **ScaleType in the ImageView** & make sure that the parent layout for the adapter (LinearLayout, RelativeLayout..) has **android:layout_height="wrap_content"**.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/my_image" />
```

Comment: I think you did not get my question. I just added a drawing to be clearer. Regards.